# java jlabel array

Tags: java

what's wrong with this? the labels[] causes an error

```
JLabel labels[] = new JLabel();
    for (int i =  0; i < 4; i++) {
       labels[i] = new JLabel("Label" + i);
       panel.add(labels[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

initialize a single Jlabel if you want to initialize array you should do like that

```
JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[4];
```

Comment: it is not related to with that code maybe there errors after that

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[4];
```

and then you have to create new instances for each array entry (otherwise array contains only nulls)

```
for(JLabel label : labels) {
  label = new JLabel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must define the array. Then you can play with the methods in it.

```
Labels = new JLabel[]{ label1, label2, label3 };

for(int i=0; i<Labels.length; i++){
         add(Labels[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with declaring JLabel array,

```
JLabel labels[] = new JLabel(); //Incorrect code
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[enter the size]; //Correct One
```